# Dotnet run/restore without internet (Offline mode)

Tags: deployment, .net-core, nuget

I have a Windows server in which I installed and restored my dotnet core project successfully (at the time when I had outbound internet connection on the server). This instance of the application is running fine now.

Now Outbound internet access has been revoked as part of data center policy. I have VPN and Remote Desktop access, though. Now, I am trying to clone my working project into a separate folder and create another instance (on a different port).

But when using `dotnet run` on my new project folder (all content except few settings are same), I am getting this error:

```
$ dotnet run
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.2.102\NuGet.targets(114,5): error :  
Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org
/v3/index.json. [C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.2.102\NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly 
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because 
connected host has failed to respond [C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx.csproj]

The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.
```

I checked `C:\Users\xxxxxx\.nuget\packages` and all required packages are available.

Both projects are running under the same Windows user profile.

I have looked up various Stackoverflow questions on the subject, but all of them talk about a proxy setting, which is not my use case.

How can I prevent `dotnet` from looking up remote nuget server as all packages are already available in the local cache.

Is building the dll locally and running on server  the only option? Cant I build it on my server in offline mode?

Comment: why is building elsewhere and only running pre-built binaries on the server undesirable?

Comment: In this specific case (when there is no internet), I would like to be sure about the source code from where a binary  is built, so that looking at Exception stack traces will be easier. If I build somewhere, the source code and binaries may quickly go out of sync, especially if I have multiple simultaneous versions. Probably, a tight version numbering on binaries may help, but for now, I think building on server is working well for me. If server has internet, we do build automation by doing a git pull on server. So even here build on server seems to be the best option.

Answer (score 6):

Ok. As it usually happens, I got the solution after posting the question on SO.

Credits: https://blog.bigfont.ca/dotnet-restore-without-an-internet-connection/

Here is a brief:

> dotnet nuget locals all --list

```
info : http-cache: C:\Users\bigfo\AppData\Local\NuGet\v3-cache  
info : global-packages: C:\Users\bigfo\.nuget\packages\         
info : temp: C:\Users\bigfo\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch
```

Then, use one of those sources during dotnet restore

```
dotnet restore --source C:\Users\bigfo\.nuget\packages\
dotnet build --no-restore
dotnet run --no-restore
```

Comment: minor improvement is to use `dotnet run --no-build`. Since you build just before running, you can shave a little time off how long it takes your app to start. `dotnet bin\Debug\<TFM>\<assemblyName>.dll` would be faster still, but you may need to `dotnet publish` and run the dll from the publish directory rather than the build directory.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the solution you discovered, is to create a `nuget.config` file that removes all nuget sources:

```xml
<configuration>
 <packageSources>
    <clear />
 </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

This way, you don't need to use special command line arguments to restore or build.

Comment: I think I tried it earlier, but it did not work. Will try it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to restore your solution or project with [NuSave](https://github.com/eli-ba/nusave). It's meant for offline use.

Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41094054/2156569